# How to add bootstrap modal content to the page before page renders

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap model shows remote url on click of a button but we want to make sure it loads along with parent page

Comment: Provide more details. Does model shows remote page content?

Comment: Yes it shows remote url content

Comment: Basically there is a JS which runs on parent page we have to make sure it executes on modal content as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *IFrame*, as soon as you set `src`, it starts loading.
Other way is to use jQuery Ajax like [`jQuery.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```js
(function(){
  // Load remote content
  
  // Remote URL
  var url = 'https://loremflickr.com/450/220';

  
  // Set source and it starts loading
  document.getElementById('remotePage').src = url;

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe id="remotePage" frameborder="0" height="250" width="100%"></iframe>        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  View Remote Content
</button>
```